# Cannot make virtual environment

Tags: python, django, shell, virtualenv

I have `virtualenvwrapper-win` installed from the command line. When I try to do `virtualenv env` (env is the name of my virtual environment I'd like to set up) I get this:

> 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I'm not sure what's wrong. Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: I haven't used virtualenvwrapper-win before but what happens if you run `workon env`?

Comment: I got back ```'workon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file```

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands :

To create virtual env - `mkvirtualenv venv_name`

To view all virtual env - `lsvirtualenv`

To activate any virtual env -  `workon venv_name`

Comment: I tried ```mkvirtualenv env``` and I got back
>'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Can you check if environment variable path is set for python or not if not please set this and try again creating virtual env.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: If PC, search for environment variables and then it's a button on the bottom of the window

Answer (score -1):

use again like this

python -m virtualenv test(name)

test\Scripts\activate